# Should we use pandas.compat.StringIO or Python 2/3 StringIO?

Tags: pandas, import, backwards-compatibility, stringio, python-2to3

StringIO is the file-like string buffer object we use when reading pandas dataframe from text, e.g. ["How to create a Pandas DataFrame from a string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string)

**Which of these two imports should we use for StringIO (within pandas)?** This is a long-running question that has never been resolved over four years.

1. `StringIO.StringIO` (Python 2) / `io.StringIO` (Python 3)

   - Advantages: more stable for futureproofing code, but forces us to version-fork, e.g. see code at bottom from EmilH.
2. `pandas.compat.StringIO`

   - [pandas.compat is a 2/3 compatibility package ("without the need for 2to3") introduced back in 0.13.0 (Jan 2014)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/whatsnew.html#id1)
   - [pandas.compat package is still marked 'private' as of 0.22 and no plans to make 'public'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html?highlight=compat) says *"Warning The pandas.core, pandas.compat, and pandas.util top-level modules are considered to be PRIVATE. Stability of functionality in those modules in not guaranteed."* although they essentially haven't broken since 0.13
   - [pandas.compat source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/compat/__init__.py) defines
     the imports `builtins, StringIO/cStringIO, BytesIO, cPickle, httplib`, iterator versions of range, filter, map and zip, plus other necessary elements for Python 3 compatibility - see the [0.13.0 whatsnew](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/whatsnew.html#id1)

Version 2/3 forking code for imports from standard (from EmilH):

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

# Note: but this is very much a poor-man's version of pandas.compat, which contains much much more
```

Note:

- `pandas.compat` has existed since pandas 0.13.0 (Jan 2014) as a subpackage within pandas
- it also [seems to have been released as a standalone package: 0.1.0 (Jun 10, 2017) and 0.1.1 (Jun 10, 2017)](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-compat/#history)

Comment: cc: @Jeff jreback ...

Comment: The lack of a standard causes both [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22605281/202229) and [breakage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530891/python-pandas-nameerror-stringio-is-not-defined).

Comment: I think this is primarily opinion based. All the approaches work so use the one that you feel most comfortable with. When I answered the referenced question I used the snippet to show what to use in both Python 3 and Python 2. Today, 4 years later I'm only using Python 3 so it's a non-issue for me. Stackoverflow is probably not the place to push for a standard on this. If it's important raise an issue on the pandas issue tracker perhaps?

Comment: @EmilH: it's not opinion-based, it depends on whether the pandas developers plan to change their guidance on `pandas.compat`. We don't even need everything inside `pandas.compat` to be stable, only the identifiers I named, but in any case it has been stable since [late 2015](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commits/master/pandas/compat/__init__.py), so their warning is overly severe

Comment: @smci I agree that today their warning is overly severe (at least for `StringIO`). But, no matter the pandas developers opinion on: **Which of these two imports should we use for StringIO (within pandas)?** the answer is still based on opinion. If the question was: **Is there an officially recommended way to use `StringIO` (within pandas)?** That would not be opinion based, but reading the docs the recommendation would still currently be to not use the `pandas.compat` (despite that being an arguably cleaner way of getting hold of `StringIO`).

Comment: @EmilH: it's not based on opinion, it's based on facts. Specifically, the current and future status of `pandas.compat`, per the pandas devel crew. (Not the doc's old 'official recommendation' and the doc on that which are clearly 3+ years out-of-date). Please look at the github links for code and issues, which I cited you. Where the current code disagrees with 4-year-old doc, ignore the doc. This wouldn't be the first time that a package's doc lagged the reality of its code, or github, by years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I followed breadcrumbs here, so perhaps still worth answering. It's not totally definitive, but current Pandas documentation suggests using the built in `StringIO` rather than it's own internal methods.

> [For examples that use the `StringIO` class, make sure you import it with `from io import StringIO` for Python 3.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#:%7E:text=For%20examples%20that%20use%20the%20StringIO%20class%2C%20make%20sure%20you%20import%20it%20with%20from%20io%20import%20StringIO%20for%20Python%203.)

Comment: Yes that's the answer these days. (I had meant to self-answer and close this years ago)

Answer (score 6):

FYI, **as of pandas 0.25, `StringIO` was removed from `pandas.compat`** ([PR #25954](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/25954)), so you'll now see:

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO' from 'pandas.compat'

This means the only answer is to **import from the [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for the update MikeT